# Twisted carving in legs or balusters

Tags: terminology

I have seen a twisted style of wood carving used in 19th-century table legs or staircase balusters. What is it called?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a type of *barley twist*.

A Google image search for "barley twist legs" brings up the following pieces, of many, each identified by a private seller or auction house as having legs with a barley twist:

[image: Barley-twist legs]